# Conditional checks of dictionaries added to a list

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

I am a complete noob. I am using: https://www.nostarch.com/pythoncrashcourse2e/

I am on Ch 6 about dictionaries. As a little side project to ensure I understand dictionaries(what I have learned about them so far, which isn't much) and to review some older stuff from the book, I wanted to create a list of beers with certain key/values to reference so that I could make suggestions to potential clients about beers(I will make this bigger and better once I have the knowledge base).

I have tried different ways to run conditional checks against dictionaries I added to a list called 'beers'. The most recent is as follows:

First step was to create the dictionaries:

```
beer_1 = {'color' : 'blonde', 'alc' : 5.5, 'volume' : '33cl', 'price' : 2.75} 

beer_2 = {'color' : 'chocolate', 'alc' : 7, 'volume' : '33cl', 'price' : 4.0} 

beer_3 = {'color' : 'red', 'alc' : 6, 'volume' : '33cl', 'price' : 3.50}
```

Step 2 was to add them to a list:

```
beers = [beer_1, beer_2, beer_3]
```

Step 3 was to print the list to make sure everything is there.

```
print(beers)
```

The,  I wanted to run the checks: (only one example so far) by running:

```
for beer in beers: 
   if 'alc' in beer == 6: 
      print("This is an amber.")
```

I don't get any output using this unless I add an 'else' statement and then it prints the else statement only. What do I need to do to accomplish what it is that I want? Namely, run checks against the dictionaries in my list to desirable characteristics of beer according to a client's choosing to make appropriate suggestions for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` method on dictionary:

```
for beer in beers: 
   if beer.get('alc', 0) == 6: 
      print("This is an amber.")
```

This method does not work:

```
if 'alc' in beer == 6:
```

because, it first evaluates `'alc' in beer` which evaluates to `True` or `False` and then it is never equals to 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you check for the key- value pair in dictionary.

You should do this by referencing to key to get the value in dictionary.

```
for beer in beers: 
   if beer['alc'] == 6: 
      print("This is an amber.")
```